# How can I find the reason for Handshake Failure for ClientHello?

Tags: https, tls1.2

I'm trying to fix a bug in a custom TLS 1.2 library.
It works for some sites and for some not.
I was able to fix connection to google.com by adding SNI extension support.
But I can't find the reason why it fails on microsoft.com?

```
TLSv1.2 Record Layer: Handshake Protocol: Client Hello
    Content Type: Handshake (22)
    Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
    Length: 73
    Handshake Protocol: Client Hello
        Handshake Type: Client Hello (1)
        Length: 69
        Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
        Random: b1a2b0f5db8e81262098074baf109bcbfa234597972087779be62c3a391de356
        Session ID Length: 0
        Cipher Suites Length: 6
        Cipher Suites (3 suites)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x0035)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x002f)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0x000a)
        Compression Methods Length: 1
        Compression Methods (1 method)
            Compression Method: null (0)
        Extensions Length: 22
        Extension: server_name (len=18)
            Type: server_name (0)
            Length: 18
            Server Name Indication extension
                Server Name list length: 16
                Server Name Type: host_name (0)
                Server Name length: 13
                Server Name: microsoft.com
        [JA3 Fullstring: 771,53-47-10,0,,]
        [JA3: 2883bc8e420c3ea85bb4b5d5081fd6e0]


TLSv1.2 Record Layer: Alert (Level: Fatal, Description: Handshake Failure)
    Content Type: Alert (21)
    Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
    Length: 2
    Alert Message
        Level: Fatal (2)
        Description: Handshake Failure (40)
```

Answer (score 0):

After some investigation i've found that microsoft.com doesn't support my list of ciphers. Actually I need to implement one of ECDHE ciphers.